# SUBSTRING in a Scalar UDF - Unexpected Return

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am working in SSMS 2012.  I have a scalar UDF that tests to see if a certain value is a 3-digit number:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test8] (@input nvarchar)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @output varchar(50)
    SET @output = CASE
        WHEN LEN(@input) <> 3 THEN 'failure' --must be 3 characters
        WHEN LEFT(@input,1) NOT LIKE '%[123456789]%' THEN 'failure' --first character must be a natural number
        WHEN SUBSTRING(@input,2,1) NOT LIKE '%[0123456789]%' THEN 'failure' --second character must be a natural number (zero inclusive)
        WHEN SUBSTRING(@input,3,1) NOT LIKE '%[0123456789]%' THEN 'failure' --third character must be a natural number (zero inclusive)
        ELSE 'success'
    END
    RETURN @output
END
```

I have the following query, in which I am trying to return records where a certain column fails when it is passed to the UDF:

```
SELECT
Col1
FROM some_table
WHERE
dbo.test8(Col2) = 'failure'
```

I have several records that would give a 'success' on this UDF (e.g., '123'), but they are returning in the query, which means the UDF is returning 'failure' on them.  What is wrong with my query?  My best guess is that it has something to do with the SUBSTRINGs.

Comment: Debugging tip: You could try modifying your return output to actually return a specific test. So, instead of returning failure, return the result of, say, `LEN(@input) <> 3`. If it checks out, move on to the next test. Once you get something you're not expecting, you've found the specific issue and can focus on resolving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not specifying the size of a (n)varchar parameter you get the default length of 1 character.

Change

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test8] (@input nvarchar)
```

to

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[test8] (@input nvarchar(4))
```